# Passing arrays to series data not working

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to plot column and the line chart in one combined chart. I have to read values from a table and pass it to the series. I have read them into an array and passing it to the data attribute(arrays val3 and val4) but it is not working. When I generate an array with data not from the table(array val2 and first_array_work), it works.

Following is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AnilKumarVallur/13x2uj7a/1/ and also the complete code is attached here.

```
`<html>
<head>
<title>Highcharts Tutorial</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cat_array = [];
    var first_array_work = [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];
    var val2 = [];
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        val2[i] = 10*i;
    }
    var first_array = [];
    var header_cat = 1;
    $("#datatable tr").eq(0).find('td').each(function(){
        if(header_cat){
            header_cat = 0;
        }
        else{
            cat_array.push($(this).text());
        }
    })
    var header_first = 1;
    var i=0;
    var val3 = [];
    $("#datatable tr").eq(1).find('td').each(function(){
        if(header_first){
            header_first = 0;
        }
        else{
            //first_array.push($(this).text());
            val3[i] = ($(this).text());
            //alert(val3[i]);
            i++;
        }
    })
    var cat = cat_array;
    var val4 = [];
    for(var m=0;m<val3.length;m++){
        val4[m] = val3[m];
    }
   var chart = {
      zoomType: 'xy'
   };
   var subtitle = {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'   
   };
   var title = {
      text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'   
   };
   var xAxis = {
      categories: cat,
      crosshair: true
   };
   var yAxis= [{ // Primary yAxis
      labels: {
         format: '{value}\xB0C',
         style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
         }
      },
      title: {
         text: 'Temperature',
         style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
         }
      }
   }, { // Secondary yAxis
      title: {
         text: 'Rainfall',
         style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
         }
      },
      labels: {
         format: '{value} mm',
         style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
         }
      },
      opposite: true
   }];
   var tooltip = {
      shared: true
   };
   var legend = {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'left',
      x: 120,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 100,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
   };
   var series= [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: val2,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

         }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
           }
        }
   ];     

   var json = {};   
   json.chart = chart;   
   json.title = title;
   json.subtitle = subtitle;      
   json.xAxis = xAxis;
   json.yAxis = yAxis;
   json.tooltip = tooltip;  
   json.legend = legend;  
   json.series = series;
   $('#container').highcharts(json);  
});
</script>
    <table id='datatable'>
        <tr><td>Amb Temp</td><td>-40</td><td>-30</td><td>-20</td><td>-10</td><td>0</td><td>10</td><td>-40</td><td>-30</td><td>-20</td><td>-10</td><td>0</td><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Active</td><td>10.0</td><td>20</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sleep</td><td>20</td><td>30</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>10</td><td>20</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the exact problem is in data type. Highcharts library is waiting for an array of floats as an input data, and you're trying to give it an array of strings. I've edited your code a little bit: https://jsfiddle.net/13x2uj7a/2/. Here I've just used `parseFloat` inside of this block:

```
    $("#datatable tr").eq(1).find('td').each(function(){
        if(header_first){
            header_first = 0;
        }
        else{
            //first_array.push($(this).text());
            val3[i] = parseFloat($(this).text());
            //alert(val3[i]);
            i++;
        }
    })
```

and could get some data from table on the graph.